# On the correct definition of a *triangle* in an additive category

Tags: category-theory

Given that we are in some additive category with "shift functors" (i.e., additive auto-equivalences) $A \mapsto A[n]$, [Mark Haiman defines](http://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math256/Derived-Cat-1-5.pdf) a *triangle* to be a sequence $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow A[1]$ **such that the composition of any two consecutive morphisms is zero**. However, after looking elsewhere, it appears that this last condition is usually not included in the definition of a triangle.

Could somebody shed some light on this? Thank you.

Comment: In presence of the other axioms for triangulated categories it follows that the composition of two consecutive morphisms in a distinguished triangle is zero. You rarely need to consider other triangles.

Comment: Here http://people.sissa.it/~floregi/stuff/topo2Beamer.pdf (slide 10) you find a proof of the fact that adiacent arrows in a distinguished triangle compose to zero, which only appeals to the rotation axiom.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: All three basic axioms are used: identities belong to distinguished triangles, the rotation axiom and the morphism axiom :-)

Comment: @Martin: c'est vrai. :)